# Get css arrow width from jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I am using cssarrowplease to generate an arrow on the left of my element. This element is a tooltip, and I'm trying to position it to other elements. I need to know the width of the arrow so I can add that to the tooltips left offset. How can I get this value from jQuery?

EDIT

```
.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 6000;
    background: rgba(50, 50, 50, .8);
    border: 2px solid rgba(50, 50, 50, .8);
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.tooltip:after, .tooltip:before {
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    left: 100%;
    top: 50%;
}

.tooltip:before {
    border-color: rgba(150, 40, 40, 0);
    border-width: 8px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    border-left-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, .8);
}

.tooltip:after {
    border-color: rgba(180, 60, 60, 0);
    border-width: 5px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    border-left-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, .8);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you use an actual DIV and style it to be an arrow instead of using :before, :after? jQuery is not able to get the width of :before,:after so, in order to get the width you would actually need to use a div as an arrow.

Example below.

```js
var widthLeft = parseInt( $(".arrow").css("border-left-width").replace("px","") );
var widthRight = parseInt( $(".arrow").css("border-right-width").replace("px","") );
var width = widthLeft + widthRight + "px";
console.log(width)
```

```css
.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 6000;
    background: rgba(50, 50, 50, .8);
    border: 2px solid rgba(50, 50, 50, .8);
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.arrow {
    border: solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    left: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border-color: rgba(150, 40, 40, 0);
    border-width: 8px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    border-left-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, .8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

<div class="tooltip">
<div class="arrow"></div>
text
</div>
</div>
```